# How to set sheet name in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have some problems getting this code to set the sheet I can imagine its because I don't `dim` it but I have tried with `dim as workbook` that doesn't work.

I tried go step by step and the "thf" have the right string in it.

```
Sub CreateSheet()
    Set tsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("For Save")
    Dim th As String
    Dim thf As String
    Dim thfs As Workbook
    th = Replace(tsheet.Range("A11").Value, "/", "-")
    thf = "SAVE" & " " & th & " " & tsheet.Range("A3").Value
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = thf
        Set thfs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(thf)
                tsheet.Ranges("A1:R201").Copy

    qsheet.Columns("A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What line of code produces an error? As good practice, you should always declare your variables. In this case you would use `Dim tsheet as worksheet`

Comment: sorry about that its the:

`Set thfs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(thf)`

It is not setting the "set" sheet "thfs" but the "thf" have the right value in it

Comment: You have declared `thfs` as a workbook in the following statement `Dim thfs As Workbook`, but are then trying to `SET` it to be a worksheet. Try changing it to `Dim thfs As Worksheet`

Comment: That did it thank you. thought I had to use the Workbook didn't know the worksheet. post it as an answer mate

Comment: Cool, glad it worked.

Comment: The best thing you can do is to put 'Option Explicit' as the first line of any VBA module. This will force you to declare all your variables, which stops an awful lots of errors.

Comment: Can be closed under the official close reason: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposted as answer. You have declared `thfs` as a workbook in the following statement `Dim thfs As Workbook`, but are then trying to `SET` it to be a worksheet. Try changing it to `Dim thfs As Worksheet`

Comment: Thanks :) I will make it as an answer then the time runs out

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a `Worksheet` variable for `thfs`, or include it in the `With` like I did below
2. A worksheet name can only be 31 characters so best to check that

Try this:

```
Sub CreateSheet()
    Dim tsheet As Worksheet
    Dim th As String, thf As String

    Set tsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("For Save")
    th = Replace(tsheet.Range("A11").Value, "/", "-")
    thf = "SAVE" & " " & th & " " & tsheet.Range("A3").Value

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        .Name = Left(thf, 31) 'remove if you're sure the length won't be over 31 characters
        tsheet.Ranges("A1:R201").Copy
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the input about the 31 characters but I'n not even close to that.